# How to retain original jpeg image size in ms word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word

I scanned an A4 document which contains only texts and save it as JPEG file format.

Now, the same image JPEG is inserted into ms word using insert, picture ... options.

1. The size of thr inserted image file is totally different from the original scanned document.
2. The text are appearing smaller but no smudging or blurry at all. But, the original scanned image is

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Change your page layout to match the size (layout) of the jpeg file.

Comment: Layout option?? It will not print the exact size. If the original size was 2x5 inch, the same size should be retained in ms word 2x5 inch.

Answer (score 0):

The default picture resolution in word is 96 dpi, and if the inserted picture resolution is not 96 dpi, the size of the picture will change.

How to view picture DPI:

Image - right-click - property - select summary in pop-up window

If the picture resolution is not 96 dpi, we need to convert it through a formula:

Suppose your picture resolution is 300 dpi.

Calculated in a formula: 300 / 96 = 3.12

We need to enter 312% in the scale.

Pictures - size and position - size - scale - modify height and width